# How to collapse a v-treeview with a button in Vuetify?

Tags: treeview, vuetify.js

How to collapse a treeview with a button ?

I tried this:

```
<v-btn @click="expanded ? (expanded = false) : (expanded = true)"
    ><v-icon>{{
        expanded ? 'mdi-arrow-collapse-all' : 'mdi-arrow-expand-all'
    }}</v-icon></v-btn
>
```

```
<v-treeview
    :items="branches"
    :open-all="expanded"
/>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            expanded: true,
            branches: [...],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But I can't get the [open-all](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#props) prop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my issue like below, opening **only** the **first depth**.

First, I changed the button in the `<template>` to:

```
<v-btn @click="toggleTreeview()"
    ><v-icon>{{
        open.length
            ? 'mdi-arrow-collapse-all'
            : 'mdi-arrow-expand-all'
    }}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Then, I'm using these props to the `<v-treeview>`:

```
<v-treeview
    :items="branches"
    item-key="id"
    :open.sync="open"
/>
```

I removed `expanded` and add `open` array:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            branches: [...],
            open: []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally, I'm using this method to toggle the treeview (in other words, fill or empty the `open` array):

```
methods: {
    toggleTreeview() {
        this.open.length
            ? (this.open = [])
            : this.branches.forEach((element) => this.open.push(element.id))
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to the treeview, and use the [`updateAll(boolean)` function](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#functions) of the v-treeview component.

```html
<v-treeview
  :items="branches"
  :open-all="expanded"
  ref="myTreeview"
/>

<v-btn @click="toggleTreeview">
  <v-icon>{{ expanded ? 'mdi-arrow-collapse-all' : 'mdi-arrow-expand-all'}}</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: true,
      branches: [...],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTreeview() {
      this.expanded = !this.expanded;
      this.$refs.mytreeview.updateAll(this.expanded); 
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's a sample [demo at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-darkness-z2t60?file=/src/components/Playground.vue):
[image]